# Dynamic Programming solution for a Recursion solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given an input `n` , find the sum of all the possible combinations of numbers `1 ... n`.
For example, if `n=3` , then all the possible combinations are

`(1),(2),(3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3)`

and their sum is

`1 + 2 + 3 + (1+2) + (1+3) + (2+3) + (1+2+3) =24`

I am able to solve this problem using `recursion`. How can I solve this problem using `Dynamic Programming` ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int sum=0,n;
int f(int pos,int s)
{
    if(pos>n)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=pos+1;i<=n;++i)
        {
            sum+=s+i;
            f(i,s+i);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
     cin>>n;
     sum=0;
     f(0,0);
     cout<<sum<<'\n';

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Though this problem can be solved in constant time using this [series](https://oeis.org/A001788).

But I want to know how this can be done using `Dynamic Programming` as I am very weak at it.

Comment: Or you could just compute it analytically: `n*(n+1)*2**(n-2)`. No loops, no recursion, no dynamic programming. Happy to post an answer with the derivation.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use dynamic programming; you can use simple arithmetic if you want.

The number of cases is 2 ^ n, since each number is either on or off for a given sum.

Each number from 1 to n is used in exactly half of the sums, so each number comes 2 ^ (n-1) times.
1 + 2 + ... + n = (n - 1) * n  / 2.

So the sum is (n - 1) * n / 2 * 2 ^ (n-1).
For n = 3, it is (4*3/2) * 4 = 24.

**EDIT**: if you really want to use dynamic programming, here's one way.
Dynamic programming makes use of saving the results of sub-problems to make the super problem faster to solve.  In this question, the sub-problem would be the sum of all combinations from 1 ... n-1.

So create a mapping from n -> (number of combinations, sum of combinations).

Initialize with 1 -> (2,1).  Because there are two combinations {0,1} and the sum is 1.  Including 0 just makes the math a bit easier.

Then your iteration step is to use the mapping.

Let's say (n-1) -> (k,s), meaning there are k sets that sum to s for 1 ... n-1.

Then the number of sets for n is k * 2 (each combination either has n or does not).
And the sum of all combinations is s + (s + k * n), since you have the previous sum (where n is missing) plus the sum of all the combinations with n (which should be k * n more than s because there are k new combinations with n in each).

So add n -> (2*k,2*s + k*n).

And your final answer is the s in n -> (k,s).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for answering.I was aware of this solution, but I am looking only for solution using `Dynamic Programming`.

Answer (score 2):

let dp[n] be the result, Therefore:

```
dp[1] = 1
dp[n] = 2 * dp[n-1] + 2^(n-1) * n
```

First, it is obvious that dp[1] = 1

Second, dp[n] is the sum which contains n and sum which didn't contains n

E.G:  dp[3] = {(1) (2) (1,2)} + {(3), (1,3), (2,3), (1,2,3)}

We can find dp[n-1] appear twice and the number of n appear 2^(n-1) times

I think maybe it is what you want.